# Shared memory thread safery in PHP

Tags: php, shared-memory

Anybody knowns using shmop_read and shmop_write is safery beetween different php request?

Read and write operations require use semaphores?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself:

Yes, if you use shmop_read and shmop_write you need use semaphore

```
shmget(0x74613e35,0x64,0x3a4,0x3,0x1,0x7fffffffb9c8) = 65540 (0x10004)
shmctl(0x10004,0x2,0x7fffffffb960,0x3,0x1,0x7fffffffb9c8) = 0 (0x0)
shmat(0x10004,0x0,0x0,0x3,0x1,0x7fffffffb9c8) = 34369576960 (0x800962000)
^CSIGNAL 2 (SIGINT)
process exit, rval = 0
```

and no see there any call to lock function